# Why native WLClient lifecycle bind to Activity lifecycle

Tags: android, android-activity, ibm-mobilefirst, lifecycle, android-lifecycle

## Short Version

I've found that WLClient lifecycle is bound to Activity. Activity lifecycle is managed by OS.

Do you have any recommendations to compensate this?

## Long Version

For Android Native project, the first step should be create a WLClient instance by the following call

```
WLClient.getInstance(Context ctx)
```

From the API document, it's a Context, not an Activity, but in reality, there would be a type cast in WLPush.java in WL framework.

It doesn't make sense to bind a WLClient to a Activity, whose life cycle is not controlled by us. So for the safety concern, each WLClient should be re-created, when a new Activity is created.

And for each re-creation, the following are needed:

1. connect to server
2. construct challenge handler

I have the following error if I passed a class (MainContext) inheriting  Application (which is a Context):

```
09-26 13:33:29.571: E/AndroidRuntime(32300): FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-2-thread-4
09-26 13:33:29.571: E/AndroidRuntime(32300): Process: com.XXXX, PID: 32300
09-26 13:33:29.571: E/AndroidRuntime(32300): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.XXX.MainContext cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
09-26 13:33:29.571: E/AndroidRuntime(32300):    at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush.<init>(WLPush.java:151)
09-26 13:33:29.571: E/AndroidRuntime(32300):    at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLClient.getPush(WLClient.java:673)
09-26 13:33:29.571: E/AndroidRuntime(32300):    at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequest.requestFinished(WLRequest.java:203)
09-26 13:33:29.571: E/AndroidRuntime(32300):    at com.worklight.wlclient.InternalRequestSender.run(AsynchronousRequestSender.java:138)
09-26 13:33:29.571: E/AndroidRuntime(32300):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-26 13:33:29.571: E/AndroidRuntime(32300):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-26 13:33:29.571: E/AndroidRuntime(32300):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current implementation is not ideal. If you'd like, you can submit a feature request to have this re-evaluated for a future release. You can submit it via: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/

The reason it is like this, is because `WLClient` has some features, such as displaying UI error messages, monitoring whether the app is in the foreground/background for heartbeat as well as push notifications support, that require an Android context.

In this case, the error you are getting is expected.

Comment: Yeah I got it. The parameter used is confusing. If an Activity is required, just specify that clearly, not an Context

Comment: @Qylin, I'll see about clarifying it in the documentation. If my answer helped you out, please mark as answered.